# Soundcloud player appears over colorbox in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, z-index, colorbox, soundcloud

I'm using [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to display images for a website. In Chrome version 11.0.696.65 only when the color box is activated, the soundcloud player appears infront of the displayed image.

I've tried changing the z-index of the colorbox, but with no success. I'm pretty sure this is a new problem with chrome/soundcloud as I wasn't having the problem before.

[image: Sound player over image]

**UPDATE** The following code works and might help someone.

```
#Add transparent mode to youtube
embeded_link.gsub!(/("http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/.{11})(")/,'\1?wmode=transparent\2')

#Add transparent mode to soundcloud
embeded_link.gsub!(/(<object height=".+" width=".+">\s*)(<param name="movie" value="http:\/\/player\.soundcloud\.com\/player\.swf)/,'\1<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>\2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to embed your Flash with `wmode="transparent"` (or `opaque`).

Here's a snippet with `wmode` inserted in both the required places.

```
<object height="81" width="100%">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F5475496"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F5475496" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> </object>
```

See: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html